# JavaScript countdown cannot parse integer numbers

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="haha">5</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){apa()}, 1000);
            var f = 5;

            function apa() {
                document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML = f;
                f--;
                apa();
            }       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to make countdown with timer and decrements, but the output come out not as integer (5, 4, 3, 2, 1,......) but stuffs like -336048 etc instead.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should not call `apa()` inside `apa` it creates a infinite recursion. The `setInterval()` will call `apa` in 1 sec intervals so no need to call it again.

```
//also there is no need to use a anonymous function you can just say
//var myVar = setInterval(apa, 1000);
var myVar = setInterval(function () { 
    apa()
}, 1000);
var f = 5;

function apa() {
    document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML = f;
    f--;
}
```

```js
var myVar = setInterval(apa, 1000); //just pass the apa reference to setInterval
var f = 5;

function apa() {
  document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML = f;
  f--;
}
```

```html
<a id="haha">5</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this . this will count only(5 4 3 2 1)

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){if(f>0) apa()},1000);
        var f=5;
         function apa() 
        {
            document.getElementById("haha").innerHTML = f;
            f--;
        }
```